# Scatterplot of diamonds of varying heights and widths based on values in Python or R

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, seaborn

I have these 2 lists in Python:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1.5, 1.7, 3.2, 4.1, 4.9]
```

I want a scatterplot of y on the vertical axis vs. x on the horizontal axis, and I want the markers to be diamonds that are proportional to their sizes.

```
x_size = [5, 7, 5, 6, 9]
y_size = [10, 9, 11, 13, 12]
```

The width of the diamond is the x_size, and the height of the diamond is y_size.

I prefer to do this in Python using Matplotlib or Seaborn, but I'm willing to also do this in R.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am  not aware of a standard method in R that allows you to adjust height and width of a shape. One normally controls size.

Here are a couple of ways to go though:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               y = c(1.5, 1.7, 3.2, 4.1, 4.9))

p1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = y), shape = 18)
p1

p2 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = x, colour = y), shape = 18)
p2

shapes <- c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
p3 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = factor(x))) +
  geom_point(aes(size = x, colour = y)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes)
p3
```

p1:

[image]

p2:

[image]

p3:

[image]